# Xposed module for Lollipop theme in Xperia P [4.1.2 JB]

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, customization, themes, xposed-framework, sony-xperia-p

I've recently rooted my Sony Xperia P and installed Xposed framework. Currently, it's running the stock ROM with latest OTA update [Android JB 4.1.2]. Can anyone please tell me if there are any stable Xposed framework modules to provide Android Lollipop theme in my device? Any practical experience? I've been browsing through various module repositories but no luck so far :(

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Hi! Questions such as "*Is there an app that does X*" are off-topic here. Visit [help/on-topic] to know what's on-topic here *[et al](http://android.stackexchange.com/help)*. However, [softwarerecs.se] is the fitting place for such questions, provided that you follow their on-topic [guidelines](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

1. Root your phone.
2. Install the Xposed Installer app from here: http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer
3. Open it, go to Framework, then click 'Install/Update' and reboot your phone..
4. Download, install and activate the module 'MonsterUI' (which gives Lollipop like Material look) from here: http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.kuaq.monsterui and reboot..
5. Now open the module (app) and select your desired options..

Comment: I tried Monster UI. Unfortunately whenever I try to theme system UI to lollipop, the phone crashes. Is there any stable version for this?

Comment: Please do not answer questions such as "*Is there an app that does X*" since they are off-topic here. Answers to such questions tend to encourage users to ask such off-topic content again. Off-topic content diminishes the desired usefulness of a website. Visit [help/on-topic] to know what's on-topic and off-topic *[et al](http://android.stackexchange.com/help)*.